# Is zooming in the browser the same as zooming on a mobile device?

Tags: android, iphone, html, css, mobile

When I press `Ctrl+` in a modern browser, the page zooms, including images; a similar effect is apparent when pinching and zooming on a mobile device. Everything on the page scales proportionally.

My question is, when the browser zooms and when the mobile device zooms are they doing the same thing internally? I'm specifically interested in the relationship of *physical pixels* with *display pixels* with *device-independent pixels*. This is a domain that can become rapidly convoluted when considering media queries and the like.

**Edit:** I've got some good answers, my appreciated. I was hoping to find out **how** they differ from a technical point of view. i.e. "one is scaling x, the other scales y". Any insight here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In my observations, no, they are not the same.  When I pinch-zoom on my mobile device it zooms in without affecting the relative page size.  When I Ctrl-+ on a PC, the page is adjusted to fit in the same screen pixels width, which alters flows to fit content in fewer "virtual" pixels.

**EDIT:**
There is also a difference between mobile pinch-zoom and mobile double-tap-zoom.  I have observed that double-tap-zoom *does* affect the flow of the page, while pinching does not.

Regarding "CSS pixels", isn't it apparent from how elements with sizes defined in `px` units are affected?  It would seem that "CSS pixels" remain how they were intended at 100%/

Comment: Relative page size is modified on a mobile device to some extent. If I zoom a fluid page on a mobile device, the content will change its wrapping (and thus, I'm assuming, reported screen width).

Comment: Your edit made depend upon the platform, my older android phone doesn't show any difference.

Comment: Looks like I was observing the "text wrap" setting; so the relative page size stays the same, but the text is wrapped as if it were fluid. I really don't like that :-/

Answer (score 1):

No, in generally browsers tweak the CSS of the existing document to change dimensions. Mobile devices scale an "image" of the document.

Comment: I see the same effect. I'm trying to get the bottom of what happens to the "css pixels" in each, and if the device independent pixels related to the act of zooming. We're, potentially, talk about two layers of "virtual pixels" on top of the physical pixel display.

Comment: Browser zoom algorithms are not universal (IE, webkit, FF). How it works varies a bit, and sometimes they break the layout due to rounding issues. This doesn't happen with mobile.

Comment: Yeah... I had noticed that. Does that mean they're adjusting the [device-independent pixel](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html#terms) layer? Ultimately, I'm trying to establish the future role of pixels in web design.

Comment: I doubt they are adjusting the pixel layer. The fact that layouts sometimes break means they're tweaking the HTML display.

Answer (score 0):

The simple answer is no they are not the same.

When pinch zoom is used with the phone everything is scaled.

when using ctrl+ on a browser CSS rules are still applied.

For example if you had a left panel that was specified as 200em then the right panel was specified to auto fill then when ctrl+ was hit the right panel will take up more space and the space used by the right panel would be reduced but the size of the text would be larger.

Some browser treat units differntly.  Some scale some don't.  For example for some browsers if px is used to specify size it will not change even when ctrl+ is hit (mostly older browsers).  As a general rule if you want things to scale when ctrl+ is hit and scale properly then the em unit is often recommended since it is based on the font size which is what is scaled when you hit ctrl+.

Unfortanatly each browser handles zooming a little differently and the only way to be sure your page will zoom as expected is to test on the browser of interest.

Comment: "often recommended since it is based on the font size which is what is scaled when you hit ctrl+". I'm not sure this is true in modern browsers; the fact that all pixel dimensions scale, including image dimensions, leads me to believe they're working on the "css pixels".

Comment: @Matt true modern browsers are very good at scaling things as you would expect them to scale when hitting ctrl+ which is why I added the "mostly older browsers".  There are still situations where things do not scale as expected.  The only unit that I know of that will scale predictably is the em unit.  The only way to know for sure how the page will scale is to test on multiple browsers.